# how to distingush multiple ajax submit in single ajax callback

Tags: 7, ajax

I trying to do add more functionality for adding video urls which I am able to do by using Ajax callback.I am referring a drupal examples for it.It has one remove one button which removes last created text field from form. **But I want a remove button for each text-field to remove it.**

I am creating textfields and remove button in form hook like

```
for ($i=0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
        $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['title'][$i] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Video Title'),
            '#default_value' => $webinar_videos[$i]->title,
        );
        $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['url'][$i] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Video Url'),
            '#default_value' => $webinar_videos[$i]->video_url,
        );
        $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['remove'][$i] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Remove'),
            '#submit' => array('webinar_add_more_remove_one'),
            '#validate' =>false,
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'webinar_add_more_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
            ),
        );
}
```

Now a 'webinar_add_more_remove_one' submit callback is like

```
function webinar_add_more_remove_one($form, &$form_state) {

    if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
        $form_state['num_names']--;
    }
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

and 'webinar_add_more_callback' this callback returns a wrapper element like

```
function webinar_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
}
```

My question is **How I can pass a video id to particular remove submit button so that I can delete particular video in 'webinar_add_more_remove_one' callback?**

Thank you in advance

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I had to do this I used this method:

When creating the form create an array to hold deleted ids:

```
$form_state['deleted_items'] = array();
```

And give each remove button an ID relating to that items index:

```
$form['names_fieldset'][$i]['remove'][$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Remove'),
    '#submit' => array('webinar_add_more_remove_one'),
    '#validate' =>false,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'webinar_add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
    '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'item-'.$i,
    ),
);
```

Then in webinar_add_more_remove_one check the id of the button that was pressed:

```
function webinar_add_more_remove_one($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['deleted_items'][] = str_replace('item-', '', $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['id']);
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

And then when building the form check the array of deleted items:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {

    if(in_array($i, $form_state['deleted_items']) continue;

    // rest of code....
}
```

You will also need to check the deleted item array in the submit and validate functions as we don't actually removed the deleted item from the $form_state array.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer,I did exactly same as you mentioned,but form is get refresh when I am clicking on any remove button and if print $form_state['deleted_items'] I am getting blank.

Comment: Make sure you are always passing $form_state by reference (with an & before it).

Comment: pass by reference was missing only for 'webinar_add_more_callback' so i given it but still whole page is get refreshed means not behaving like ajax

Comment: Yes, this will only work with ajax requests. If you refresh the whole page then you will lose the whole of $form_state.

Comment: Yes,I mean when I am clicking on any remove button then page get refreshed.I am not refreshing it manually.

Comment: The id's which we are giving to remove button are coming properly when i am inspecting it.but when i am checking it in $form_state['clicked_button'] always giving 'id' of last remove button on each remove button click.

Comment: Hey but thank you atleast I got some idea that how i can do it.I will debug and check if anything wrong from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed one missing bracket in this line:
if(in_array($i, $form_state['deleted_items']) continue;

there is a missing ) before continue;

it should be : if(in_array($i, $form_state['deleted_items'])) continue;